# Why cant I use `Invokemember("click")` to click my button programatically?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to fetch data from a website in my application through a `WebBrowserControl`.  I can successfully log in, but when I call `btnsearch.Invokemember("click")` programmatically I receive a  JavaScript error.  If I click the button interactively on the `WebBrowserControl` I receive no error and everything works fine.

In the aspx page I have one JavaScript function for calling an Ajax Panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   
window["ctl00_WorkSpace_ctlCustAVIHistory_ajxResultPanel"] = new RadAjaxPanelNamespace.RadAjaxPanel({ClientID:"ctl00_WorkSpace_ctlCustAVIHistory_ajxResultPanel",EnableOutsideScripts:false,EnablePageHeadUpdate:true,Url:"/app/ModuleCustomer/ViewAVITransactions.aspx",LoadingPanelID:"ctl00_WorkSpace_ctlCustAVIHistory_LoadingPanel1",ActiveElementID:"",ClientEvents:{OnRequestStart:"",OnRequestSent:"",OnResponseReceived:"",OnResponseEnd:""},FormID:"aspnetForm",UniqueID:"ctl00$WorkSpace$ctlCustAVIHistory$ajxResultPanel"});/*]]>*/
</script>
```

It produces a UniqueID.  If we click on `btnsearch` through code this unique id is null.

```
function onClickButton(rName) 
{
    if(validateData())
    {     
        document.getElementById("ctl00_WorkSpace_ctlCustAVIHistory_hdnReset").value = "0";    
        ctl00_WorkSpace_ctlCustAVIHistory_ajxResultPanel.AjaxRequest("NewSearch"); ///these caling down function       
    }      
}

RadAjaxPanelNamespace.RadAjaxPanel.prototype.AjaxRequest = function (eventArgument) {       
    this.AjaxRequestWithTarget(this.UniqueID, eventArgument);//this.UniqueID giving null from program click mouse click it is giving correct id 
};
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
    private const string STR_Field_userid = "field_userid";
    private const string STR_Field_password = "field_password";
    private const string STR_Submit = "submit";            

        document.GetElementById(STR_Field_userid).InnerText = UserId;
        document.GetElementById(STR_Field_password).InnerText = Password;
        document.Forms[0].InvokeMember(STR_Submit);
```